# MySQL: How to get percentage difference between rows based upon date

Tags: mysql

```
ID     report_Date     total_points
---    -----------     -------------
123    2016-07-01      300
123    2016-07-02      600
333    2016-07-01      234
333    2016-07-02      434
```

Looking how to do a MySQL / SQL query that would find the percentage different of total_points based upon two dates provided.

So if I queried it for 2016-07-01 and 2016-07-02 it would give me:

- ID
- Percentage_Difference between the 2016-07-01 total_points and 2016-07-02 total_points

Results like:

```
ID    Percentage_Difference
---   ---------------------
123   100
333   85.47
```

Suggestions on the best way to handle?

Comment: What would the result look like?

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: @Strawberry updated. thanks.

Comment: Always 2 dates?  could there be more? would you want difference on a line by line or just between the min/max?  ordered by report date?  too many unknowns to really address.

Comment: @xQbert ... the goal is to query a database around 1:00am every morning and look up and compare the results from the previous two dates. So if I queried it tomorrow (July 27) I would want it to compare the total_points from 2016-07-25 with 2016-07-26 and get the percentage difference.

Comment: And what query have you tried? You need to at least try and ask how to fix it. Otherwise i appears that you are just asking us to do free coding. By the way report_date hold just date?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.id
     , ((y.total_points-x.total_points)/x.total_points) * 100 pct
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.id = x.id
   AND y.report_date = '2016-07-02' 
 WHERE x.report_date = '2016-07-01';
```

x.report_date can be calculated from the y.report_date if you wish, but that requirement wasn't in your original question.

Note that 'ID' usually implies a surrogate PRIMARY KEY. In this instance, you appear to have a compound PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect. Also thank you so much for walking me through the submission process and making my request clearer.